# airflow command line parameter for adhoc run?

Tags: airflow

We have just started including airflow for scheduling. One of my scripts runs daily. It uses the template parameter ({{ ds_nodash }}) to get the dates. But I have to rerun for one day load (Past dated), how can I provide input parameter. Input parameter will override the ds_nodash.

```
I have :
trade_acx_ld_cmd = "/home/airflow/projects/wrapper/gen_bq_gcs_file_load.sh trade_acx.csv l1_gcb_trxn trade {{ ds_nodash }} " 

Would like to run for 
trade_acx_ld_cmd = "/home/airflow/projects/wrapper/gen_bq_gcs_file_load.sh trade_acx.csv l1_gcb_trxn trade **20190601** "
```

**Code snippet Below:**

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_check_operator import BigQueryCheckOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 6, 19),
    'email': ['sanjeeb@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('create-data-set-job', default_args=default_args)
projct_dr='/home/airflow/projects/'

trade_acx_ld="/home/airflow/projects/wrapper/gen_bq_gcs_file_load.sh" 
trade_acx_ld_cmd = "/home/airflow/projects/wrapper/gen_bq_gcs_file_load.sh trade_acx.csv l1_gcb_trxn trade {{ ds_nodash }} " 


t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

if os.path.exists(trade_acx_ld):
   t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'Dataset_create',
        bash_command=trade_acx_ld_cmd,
        dag=dag
   )
else:
    raise Exception("Cannot locate {0}".format(trade_acx_ld_cmd))

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just manually trigger the DAG using `airflow trigger_dag`. The `{{ ds_nodash }}` will take `execution_date` so if you trigger the DAG with an old execution date, `{{ ds_nodash }}` will use that older `execution_date` instead of today's date.

You can pass the `execution_date` to `trigger_dag` command as follows.

```
airflow trigger_dag gcs-file-load-job -e "2019-01-01"
```

Comment: But how to pass the override the parameter. airflow trigger_dag gcs-file-load-job 20190101. How the dag will read the parameter. airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: 20190101

Comment: `airflow trigger_dag gcs-file-load-job -e "2019-01-01"`